# How to define the href of css link in Twig template

Tags: php, twig, template-engine

I have the following app structure:

```
index.php
<templates>
|____________ <theme1>
              |
              index.html 
              <css>
              |______________style.css
```

In index.html the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="lt-ie10" lang="en" > <![endif]-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en" >

<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Foundation 5</title>

      <!-- If you are using the CSS version, only link these 2 files, you may add app.css to use for your overrides if you like -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

In index.php the following code:

```
<?php
require_once("../twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php");
Twig_Autoloader::register();
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates/theme1/');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
                              'cache' => 'compilation_cache',
                              ));
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('index.html');
echo $template->render(array('desc' => 'variables', 'go' => 'here'));
```

I realized that Twig could able to include the static path of the css file and modify it. However, what can I add as a variable or something else before the path in `href="{{?}}css/style.css">` to make it accessible for the final displayed page?

**Notice** My app is very simple and it does not use symfony. I use version 1.16.0 of [twig](/questions/tagged/twig).

Comment: Maybe you could use the absolute path to the css? That would also make it simple to add them to pages in subpaths (http://example.com/foo/bar/something.html).

Comment: @user3557327 It is not an option because accessing the website from different URLs will corrupt the design i.e `localhost, 127.0.0.1, domain.com, www.domain.com` etc

Comment: As long as it's always in the root of the domain, you can just use ´/path/to/style.css´ (note the starting slash) without specifying the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with limited solution: as follows:

in index.php I used `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and concatenated it with the theme path then setting them in a Twig variable used in the template file index.html:

```
<?php
/** Config **/
$config = array(
    'themeURI' => 'templates/theme1/',
);
/*****************/
require_once("../twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php");
Twig_Autoloader::register();
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($config['themeURI']);
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
'cache' => 'compilation_cache',
'auto_reload' => true,
));
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('index.html');
echo $template->render(array('desc' => 'variables', 'themePath' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$config['themeURI']));
```

Then in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="lt-ie10" lang="en" > <![endif]-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en" >

<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Foundation 5</title>

      <!-- If you are using the CSS version, only link these 2 files, you may add app.css to use for your overrides if you like -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{themePath}}css/style.css">
```

**The limitation** in this solution when using it in php files from subdirectories of the root, it should need to modify the value `$config['themeURI']` to relatively match the new path and may need to change the path of `require` the twig's Autoloader too.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
require_once("../twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php");
Twig_Autoloader::register();
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates/theme1/');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
                              'cache' => 'compilation_cache',
                              ));
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('index.html');
echo $template->render(array('desc' => 'variables', 'go' => 'here','assets'=>'themePath/theme1/assets'));
```

and this is in your templete

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="lt-ie10" lang="en" > <![endif]-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en" >

<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Foundation 5</title>

      <!-- If you are using the CSS version, only link these 2 files, you may add app.css to use for your overrides if you like -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{assets}}css/style.css">
```